# Button click event not working inside repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, buttonclick, asprepeater

I am working on a project where I am using a repeater control and in its item data bound event I am adding some data and two buttons-edit and delete.But click event of my buttons is not working and when I click any of these two buttons my repeater data get disappeared.

Following is my code

```
protected void fillrptmapping()
{
    ds = objcce1.selectSubject(schoolcode);
    rptmapping.DataSource = ds;
    rptmapping.DataBind();
}
protected void rep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Label lblsubcode = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblsubcode");
        Table tblmapping = (Table)e.Item.FindControl("tblmapping");
        int subcode =Convert.ToInt32(lblsubcode.Text.ToString());
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        ds1 = objcce1.selectSubjectskillmapping(schoolcode);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        ds2 = objcce1.selectAssessfullmapping(schoolcode);
        DataRow[] dr1;
        DataRow[] dr2;

                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                tr.Width = 300;
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                tr.Width = 300;
                tc.Height = 100;
                //selecting skillmappingcodes
                dr1 = ds1.Tables[0].Select("subjectgroupcode='" + subcode + "'");
                for (int j = 0; j < dr1.Length; j++)
                {
                    Label lblskill = new Label();
                    lblskill.CssClass = "lblskilltxt";
                    lblskill.Text = dr1[j]["skillname"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                    tc.Controls.Add(lblskill);
                    dr2 = ds2.Tables[0].Select("skillmappingcode='" + dr1[j]["skillmappingcode"] + "'");
                    for (int k = 0; k < dr2.Length; k++)
                    {
                        ImageButton imgedit = new ImageButton();
                        imgedit.ImageUrl = "../Images/edit.jpg";
                        imgedit.Width = 25;
                        imgedit.Height = 25;
                        imgedit.ID = dr2[k]["assessmentareamappingcode"].ToString();
                        imgedit.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imgeditassessmapping_OnClick);
                        //Button btnedit = new Button();
                        //btnedit.ID = dr2[k]["assessmentareamappingcode"].ToString();
                        //btnedit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.imgeditassessmapping_OnClick);
                        ImageButton imgdelete = new ImageButton();
                        imgdelete.Width = 25;
                        imgdelete.Height = 25;
                        imgdelete.ImageUrl = "../Images/delete.jpg";
                        imgdelete.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(this.imgdeleteassessmapping_OnClick);
                        Label lblarea = new Label();
                        lblarea.Text = dr2[k]["assessmentareaname"].ToString() + "<br/><br/>";
                        tc.Controls.Add(btnedit);
                        tc.Controls.Add(imgdelete);
                        tc.Controls.Add(lblarea);
                    }
                }
                //selecting subjectgroup in area table
                dr2 = ds2.Tables[0].Select("subgroupcode='" + subcode + "'");
                for (int l = 0; l < dr2.Length; l++)
                {
                    ImageButton imgedit = new ImageButton();
                    imgedit.Width = 25;
                    imgedit.Height = 25;
                    imgedit.ImageUrl = "../Images/edit.jpg";
                    imgedit.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(this.imgeditassessmapping2_OnClick);
                    ImageButton imgdelete = new ImageButton();
                    imgdelete.Width = 25;
                    imgdelete.Height = 25;
                    imgdelete.ImageUrl = "../Images/delete.jpg";
                    imgdelete.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(this.imgdeleteassessmapping2_OnClick);
                    Label lblarea = new Label();
                    lblarea.Text = dr2[l]["assessmentareaname"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                    tc.Controls.Add(imgedit);
                    tc.Controls.Add(imgdelete);
                    tc.Controls.Add(lblarea);
                }
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                tblmapping.Rows.Add(tr);            
    }
}
protected void imgeditassessmapping_OnClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Button img = sender as Button;
    string assessmappingcode = img.ID;
    ds =objcce1.selectAssessSkill(schoolcode, assessmappingcode);
    foreach (ListItem item in drpsubjectoption.Items)
    {
        if (item.Value == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["subjectgroupcode"].ToString())
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
    rblmapping.SelectedIndex = 0;
    spanskill.Visible = true;
    drpmappingskill.Visible = true;
    foreach (ListItem item in drpmappingskill.Items)
    {
        if (item.Value == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["skillcode"].ToString())
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
    pnlassessmapping.Visible = true;
    foreach (ListItem item in drpassessmapping.Items)
    {
        if (item.Value == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["assessmentareacode"].ToString())
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
    foreach (ListItem item in drpmarkingtype.Items)
    {
        if (item.Text == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["type"].ToString())
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
    foreach (ListItem item in rbldesc.Items)
    {
        if (item.Text == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["desindreq"].ToString())
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
    btnsavemapping.Text = "Update";
}
protected void imgdeleteassessmapping_OnClick(object sender,ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
}
```

ASPX page code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptmapping" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rep_ItemDataBound" >
                    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblsubcode" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "subgroupcode")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblsubject" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "subname")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="imgeditassessmapping_OnClick"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Table ID="tblmapping" runat="server" Width="300" BorderColor="Black" GridLines="both"></asp:Table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                         
                         </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Screenshot before button click

[image]

Screenshot after button click
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how your dynamic controls are being generated. They will need to be generated with the same IDs each time your page loads (i.e. on first load and on subsequent loads/post backs).

If the button doesn't exist (hasn't been generated) at the stage of the page lifecycle where it fires event handlers (e.g. button click events) then the event handler won't fire.

In general, the symptoms suggest that your ItemDataBound event handler isn't firing on postback; you may only be data binding if the request is not a postback. Getting the event to fire on each page request will help, but overall it would be better if you could have those buttons on the page all of the time, rather than dynamically generate them. That would give you a more reliable event handler.

Comment: but i can't use buttons on the page here as my data is dynamic or you please suggest how can I do this in this situation actually I have two kinds of mapping:subjects--skill-area or I can have subjects-area

Comment: That is fair enough, you can't add the buttons as static controls. You could maybe do the dynamic generation of code in the item template rather than in the item data bound, but that's not really the fundamental problem you're experiencing.

The fundamental problem appears to be that the repeater is not being data bound on postback. Are you making a call to Page.DataBind() or rep.DataBind anywhere in code that you haven't quoted?

Comment: ya i am making call to repeater databind method...may i add that code for your reference

Comment: I have added the method please check fillrptmapping()

Comment: Ok I'm trying to figure out where in the page lifecycle the data binding is done. So, in which page event handler (e.g. Page_Load) is fillrptmapping() called, or is the method that calls fillrptmapping() called, or is the method that calls the method that calls.... you get the idea.